# Image content aware patching (autocompletion) in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I am extracting an object from an image, after finishing the extraction I am replacing the object (defined by a connected component) with white pixels. After that I want to fix the original image as much as possible so that it looks like as if I didn't remove the object from it. Here is a [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yX1K.jpg) that demonstrates what I want to do.

Does opencv include content aware patching algorithms that achieve this effect? I am currently using opencv and c++, if opencv doesn't support this, are there any well known c++ libraries that does this?

If this task is easy to achieve with opencv or other libraries I would appreciate a small code/link to a sample of usage.

Comment: You're looking for [inpainting](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/xphoto/doc/inpainting/inpainting.html). See [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_photo/py_inpainting/py_inpainting.html) for a small tutorial

Comment: Wow Thanks Miki !! exactly what I wanted, thanks for the link also, I went ahead and searched for inpainting and found this c++ sample code: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/inpaint.cpp
That really helped me me a lot :)

Comment: Hey Joseph, I'm looking for the same thing. From your past-research, what was the library that produced the best results?

Comment: Did Image Inpainting worked for this? In my implementation it didn't produce good results.